# Laravel where table with relationships

Tags: laravel, relationship, where-clause

I’m build a app with laravel 8. This app has table order and table tracking. The order and tracking has a one to many relation, the models are like below:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['tracking'];

    public function tracking() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tracking::class);
    }
}

class Tracking extends Model
{
    public function order() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Now I want query the orders filtering them by status in the last tracking inserted. For exemple, with the data below:

```
Order 
ID         VALUE
1          100.00
2          200.00
3          300.00

Tracking
ID     ORDER_ID  STATUS     CREATED_AT
1      1         Accept     2022-03-01 00:00:00
2      1         Paid       2022-03-02 00:00:00
3      2         Accept     2022-03-01 00:00:00
4      2         Paid       2022-03-02 00:00:00
5      2         Cancel     2022-03-03 00:00:00
6      3         Accept     2022-03-01 00:00:00
7      3         Paid       2022-03-02 00:00:00
```

If the param in where clause is status = Paid, I want return order with id 1 and 3, with all tracking related.

I try to use whereHas like this:

```
$query = Order::query();

$query->whereHas('tracking', function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('status', '=', 'Paid');
});
$orders = $query->paginate(10);
```

but this make a query in all tracking, and I need query only if the last status is like Paid.

And I need data like this:

```
Order ID   VALUE     TRACKING
1          100.00    [[ID: 1, STATUS: Accept], [ID: 2, STATUS: Paid]]
3          300.00    [[ID: 6, STATUS: Accept], [ID: 7, STATUS: Paid]]
```

Notice, that order with id 2 has Paid in 2022-03-02 but in 2022-03-03 00:00:00 its canceled, so this wont appear.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. You want all the orders using a URL like www.mywebsite.com/orders/paid or www.mywebsite.com/orders/accept, where the last part of the URL is the status of the Tracking table, right?

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Yes, can be. The param is send by url. The doubt is how can I make a query with filter by last inserted tracking status.

Comment: Can you please post your URL here? Do you want all orders with a status or the last status of an order?

Comment: Yeah.. /orders/{status}. And I need all orders filtering by the last status.

Comment: Well. Then it is not required to pass the status in the URL as your requirements does not depend on the status but last status. Give me some time.

Comment: Yes, I need.. Because in front end I have a select to choose status to filtering. And in the backend I recovery this status and want return only orders that have the last status like status send by front end

Comment: In my previous exemple, if I send paid status, only order 1 is returned.

Comment: usually whereHas works for such scenarios, it will be better if you add your models and controller code  to your question

Comment: Znar, thanks for reply.. I update the question and insert more information. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the situation right now. So, suggesting the following solution without any performance testing. I hope it will solve your issue.

```php
DB::table("tracking")
->join("order", function($join){$join;})
->select("tracking.order_id", "order.val", "max (tracking.created_at) as status_updated")
->where("order.id", "=", tracking.order_id)
->groupBy("tracking")
->get();
```

Comment: Thaks for help.. But this not resolve all problems. I update the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** My previous answer was totally wrong, so here's another attempt:

An easier way to do this probably would be to define an extended relationship in the Order model:

```php
// App\Models\Order
public function active_tracking() {
    return $this->tracking()->where('status', 'Paid');
}
```

Then you can just fetch your orders with with active Tracking records:

```php
Order::with('active_tracking')->whereHas('active_tracking')->get();
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for reply. This not resolve the question, because with this query the order with id 2 is returned. The order with id 2 is Paid, but in next day was be cancelled. But, I want the order with id 2 should not be send.

Comment: I updated my answer. The order query will only fetch orders that have a paid tracking record. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

### Update 1.2

According to my comment, I have updated my answer. I've a nice idea also is that if the last `track` of the `order` has not has a `Cancel` value I'll return this track else, I'll not return it.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

$orders = Order::with('tracks')->withCount('tracks')->get();
$filteredOrders = [];

$orders->each(function ($order) use (&$filteredOrders) {
    $order->tracks->each(function ($track) use ($order, &$filteredOrders) {
        if ($order->tracks[$order->tracks_count - 1]->STATUS != "Cancel") {
            array_push($filteredOrders, $order);
        }
    });
});

// Paginate the filtered array
return new LengthAwarePaginator($filteredOrders, count($filteredOrders), 10);
```

Comment: Mahmoud thanks for reply. But this solution not work for me. This is only ordering the orders. In this case the order with id 2 will be return, because this has the Paid status in tracking, but the last status is canceled. I want   the order with id 2 should not be send.

Comment: FINALLY, I discovered your problem. Your problem is that you search through the `tracks` that their `status` is `Paid` and this is an invalid approach because you need to see if the track is canceled or not So, you need to get all `tracks` with all `status` then filter them as you want.

Comment: Thanks more one time.. This solution is more closer that I meet. But it's not resolve all, because I use method to paginate. And this mode this not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The wanted result is a bit complex to achieve, so we need to pay attention to how we'll achieve it.

To do so, let's decompose the fetching process into parts :

1. we want to select the following columns :

   - `order_id` and `value` from `orders` table.
   - `tracking_id`, `status` and `created_at` from the related `tracking` records. Those related records will be fetched using an `INNER JOIN` clause on `tracking.order_id = orders.id`.
2. Say we need to filter by `status = 'paid'` so in the query we'll likely to have something like `where tracking.status = 'paid'`.
3. The wanted result can be described as follows: `GET ME orders WHERE LATEST TRACKING STATUS IS 'paid'` which means if the latest `tracking.status` for a specific `order` is not `'paid'` then we don't want that order, nor its `tracking`s, at all.
4. To achieve the above statement, we need to know the **latest** `tracking` record related to `order` and if that related record has a `status` equals to `paid` then fetch all the related records for that `order`.

Here's an `SQL` query that fetches the wanted results when we need `tracking.status = 'paid'` :

```sql
-- selects the needed columns
SELECT `orders`.`id` AS `order_id`, `value`, `t`.`id` AS `tracking_id`, `t`.`status`
FROM `orders`
-- fetch the related "tracking" records for each order in the set. The table "tracking" is aliased as "t" for simplicity
INNER JOIN `tracking` `t` ON `t`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
-- we need to get only the related records ONLY when the latest "tracking" saved for the current "order" is the status we want (in our case "paid")
WHERE (
    -- this subquery gets the status of the latest added "tracking" of each "order"
    -- check below sub queries
    SELECT `status`
    FROM `tracking`
    WHERE `order_id` = `orders`.`id` AND `id` = (
        -- this subquery gets the "id" of the latest added "tracking"
        -- check below sub query
        SELECT `id`
        FROM `tracking`
        WHERE `order_id` = `orders`.`id` AND `created_at` = (
            -- this subquery filters the records and returns the "created_at" values of the latest added "tracking"
            SELECT `created_at`
            FROM `tracking`
            WHERE `order_id` = `orders`.`id`
            -- instead of using "max" function we can simply get the first record in the reverse order (DESC)
            ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 1
        )
    )
) = 'paid'
```

Let me try to translate the above query into Laravel's query builder:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

/** inform the query builder that the "orders" table is main table in the query */
DB::table('orders')
    /** instruct to select those columns */
    ->select('orders.id as order_id', 'orders.value', 't.status', 't.created_at') 
    /** have an INNER JOIN clause to get the related "tracking" records */
    ->join('tracking as t', 't.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->where('t.status', function ($q) {
        /** creates a subquery to get the status of the last inserted related "tracking" */
        $q->select('status')
            ->from('tracking')
            ->whereColumn('order_id', 'orders.id')
            ->where('created_at', function ($q) {
                /** a subquery to get the latest inserted tracking record (only the last will be returned) */
                $q->select('created_at')
                    ->from('tracking')
                    ->whereColumn('order_id', 'orders.id')
                    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
                    ->limit(1);
            });
    })->get(); /** execute the query */
```

> The above query was not tested so it's better that you take some time to test it and tweak it the way you want.

Based on the data sample provided in the question, the above `SQL` query should return :

| order_id | value | tracking_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.00 | 1 | Accept |
| 1 | 100.00 | 2 | Paid |
| 3 | 300.00 | 6 | Accept |
| 3 | 300.00 | 7 | Paid |

Hope i have pushed you further.

Comment: ths, thanks for reply.. This solution not resolve my problem, because I need only one line for each order and the status must have return like a array of status. Like this Order::with('tracks')->paginate()

Comment: As i said, you can build upon it and tweak it the way you want.